# How do I escape color codes in Bash?

Tags: bash, ansi-colors

I have some color codes in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m'       # begin blinking
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;38;5;74m'  # begin bold
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'           # end mode
```

This adds some color to my man pages. However, when I use `env`, bash still interprets the color codes:

```
$ env | grep LESS
LESS_TERMCAP_mb=
LESS_TERMCAP_md=
LESS_TERMCAP_me=
```

Screenshot:

[image: env colors]

How can I escape these strings so I can see them as string literals? Ideally something like `env | escape_color_codes_somehow`.

Comment: You will never escape color codes in bash.  They will haunt you forever...

Comment: `cat -e` (depending on your implementation of `cat`) will display a printable ASCII representation of otherwise unprintable characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
[STEP 101] $ echo ${!LESS_*}
LESS_TERMCAP_mb LESS_TERMCAP_md LESS_TERMCAP_me LESS_TERMCAP_se LESS_TERMCAP_so LESS_TERMCAP_ue LESS_TERMCAP_us
[STEP 102] $ for varname in ${!LESS_*}; do \
                 printf '%s=%q\n' $varname "${!varname}"; \
             done
LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m'
LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;37m'
LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'
LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'
LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;44;33m'
LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'
LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[00;32m'
[STEP 103] $
```

From [bash manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html):

> **`${parameter}`**
>
> > If the first character of `parameter` is an exclamation point (`!`), and `parameter` is not a *nameref*, it introduces a level of **variable indirection**.   Bash  uses  the value  of  the  variable  formed from the rest of `parameter` as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of `parameter` itself.  This is known as *indirect expansion*.  If `parameter` is a *nameref*, this expands to the name of the  variable  referenced  by  `parameter`  instead of performing the complete indirect expansion.  The exceptions to this are the expansions of `${!prefix*}` and `${!name[@]}` described below.
>
> **`${!prefix*}`**
>   **`${!prefix@}`**
>
> > Names matching `prefix`.  Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with `prefix`, separated by the first character of  the  `IFS`  special  variable. When `@` is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each variable name expands to a separate word.